# Login with array?

Tags: arrays, authentication, swift3

i want to login with array. i have 2 array userName and user password.
i can check with if but i must use for loop because if i have a lot of users, it could be problem for me. this is my code;

```
@IBAction func LoginButton(_ sender: Any) {


   if _username.text == userNameArr[1] && _password.text == passwordArr[1]{

        print("login successful")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
    }

    else if _username.text == userNameArr[0] && _password.text == passwordArr[0]{

        print("login successful")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
    }

    else {
        self.createAlert(titleText: "error!", messageText: "user name or password wrong!")

        print("login unsuccessful")
        print(userNameArr[1],passwordArr[1])
        print(userNameArr[0],passwordArr[0])

    }
```

how can i check it in for loop or other way? if i have more than two users (maybe 100) i can not check it. i am waiting your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's basically how you refactor a piece of code to a for loop.

1. Find a pattern. This can be a number that increases or decreases constantly. In this case, the indices increase:

   ```
   else if _username.text == userNameArr[0] && _password.text == passwordArr[0]{
   //                                    ^                                   ^
   ```
2. Write a for loop that loops from the start of the pattern, to the end of the pattern. In this case, you start at 0 and end at the array's count - 1.

   ```
   for i in 0..<userNameArr.count {

   }
   ```
3. Put one item in the pattern inside the for loop and delete everything else in the pattern.

   ```
   for i in 0..<userNameArr.count {
       if _username.text == userNameArr[0] && _password.text == passwordArr[0]{

           print("login successful")
           performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
       }
   }
   ```
4. Replace the increasing number with `i`:

   ```
   for i in 0..<userNameArr.count {
       if _username.text == userNameArr[i] && _password.text == passwordArr[i]{

           print("login successful")
           performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
       }
   }
   ```
5. Use common sense to put the code that's not in the pattern into this.

   ```
   var loggedIn = false
   for i in 0..<userNameArr.count {
       if _username.text == userNameArr[i] && _password.text == passwordArr[i]{

           print("login successful")
           performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
           loggedIn = true
           break
       }
   }
   if !loggedIn {
      self.createAlert(titleText: "error!", messageText: "user name or password wrong!")

       print("login unsuccessful")
       print(userNameArr[1],passwordArr[1])
       print(userNameArr[0],passwordArr[0])
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in userNameArr.count{
    if _username.text == userNameArr[i] && _password.text == passwordArr[i]{

        print("login successful")
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "login", sender: self)
```

break
        }

```
    else {
        self.createAlert(titleText: "error!", messageText: "user name or password wrong!")

        print("login unsuccessful")
        print(userNameArr[i],passwordArr[i])

    }
    }
```